# MySQL myisam database 400,000 rows 35 seconds for full text search

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, full-text-search, explain

I have a table with 400,000 rows.  I am using fulltext search on my website.  When the table has 250,000 rows or less, searches take a few seconds to load, however when increasing this to 400,000 it is taking 35 seconds to search for a product.

Here is an example query I use for searching:

```
SELECT *,
   (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(index.brand_name) > 18
         THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(index.brand_name, 1, 18), '...')
         ELSE index.brand_name
    END) AS brand_name
from `index`
where MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) and `category_id` = '1' order by     MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST (:search2 IN BOOLEAN MODE) desc
```

I used the explain statement which showed:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,index,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,385624,"Using where; Using filesort"
```

I then added a fulltext index for the field product_name, and ran explain again:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,index,fulltext,ft_product_name,ft_product_name,0,NULL,1,"Using where; Using filesort"
```

However this has not made any improvement to the speed, can anyone help?

Comment: Do you index anything?

Comment: How long does the query take if you remove the `ORDER BY` clause, as well as the computed `brand_name`?

Comment: 20 seconds or more without ORDER BY and CASE for brand name - however if i run the same search a second time it seems to be instant - is MySQL remembering these searches?

Comment: im also running SELECT COUNT(*) from `index` where MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) and `category_id` = '1' to get the row count for pagination

Comment: Yes, you hit the [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache.html). what is the query time, and how many rows are returned *without* `AND category_id = 1` (which I hadn't noticed before)?

Comment: says Showing rows 0 - 24 (14030 total, Query took 0.1807 sec) on phpmyadmin but this was actually 30+ seconds to show the results

Comment: This could be an issue with the way PhpMyAdmin fetches the results. If you have direct access to MySQL, it would be interesting to issue and time the query from the command line (with and without `AND category_id = 1`). How many rows are returned with `AND category_id = 1`?

Comment: I have tried through phpmyadmin, a search on the site, and through the mysql terminal - mysql terminal took so long I had to stop it, search on the site is always around 20-40 seconds